# Ejecting after injecting DLL from running process

Tags: c++, dll-injection

I wrote this function to inject DLL into running process:

```
DLL_Results CDLL_Loader::InjectDll()
{
    DWORD ThreadTeminationStatus;
    LPVOID VirtualMem;
    HANDLE hProcess, hRemoteThread;
    HMODULE hModule;

    if (!isInit())
        return NOT_INIT;

    if (isInjected())
        return DLL_ALREADY_HOOKED;

    hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, ProcessID);
    if (hProcess == NULL)
        return PROCESS_ERROR_OPEN;

    VirtualMem = VirtualAllocEx (hProcess, NULL, strlen(DllFilePath), MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
    if (VirtualMem == NULL)
        return PROCESS_ERRORR_VALLOC;

    if (WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPVOID)VirtualMem, DllFilePath, strlen(DllFilePath), NULL) == 0)
    {
        VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, NULL, (size_t)strlen(DllFilePath), MEM_RESERVE|MEM_COMMIT);
        CloseHandle(hProcess); 
        return PROCESS_ERROR_WRITE;
    }

    hModule = GetModuleHandle(L"kernel32.dll");
    hRemoteThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, NULL, 0, 
                        (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)GetProcAddress(hModule, "LoadLibraryA"),
                          (LPVOID)VirtualMem, 0, NULL);

    if (hRemoteThread == NULL)
    {
        FreeLibrary(hModule);
        VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, NULL, (size_t)strlen(DllFilePath), MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT);
        CloseHandle(hProcess); 
        return PROCESS_ERROR_CREATE_RTHREAD;
    }

    WaitForSingleObject(hRemoteThread, INFINITE);
    GetExitCodeThread(hRemoteThread, &ThreadTeminationStatus);
    FreeLibrary(hModule);

    VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, NULL, (size_t)strlen(DllFilePath), MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT);
    CloseHandle(hRemoteThread);
    CloseHandle(hProcess); 
    injected = true;
    return DLLHOOK_OK;
}
```

And It works great, but when i was trying to eject the dll i was unable to find information about unhooking.. i was trying to build some function to do it and i think i'm close
this is what i've got so far:

is that the right way? if so what parameter should i pass in createRemoteThread instade of VirtualMem (That was used in the injecting function)...

```
DLL_Results CDLL_Loader::EjectDll()
{
    DWORD ThreadTeminationStatus;
    HANDLE hProcess, hRemoteThread;
    HMODULE hModule;

    if (isInjected())
        return DLLEJECT_OK;

    hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, ProcessID);
    if (hProcess == NULL)
        return PROCESS_ERROR_OPEN;

    hModule = GetModuleHandle(L"kernel32.dll");
    hRemoteThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, NULL, 0, 
                        (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)GetProcAddress(hModule, "FreeLibrary"),
                          /*(LPVOID)VirtualMem <- What do i need to send here?*/, 0, NULL);

    if (hRemoteThread != NULL)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(hRemoteThread, INFINITE);
        GetExitCodeThread(hRemoteThread, &ThreadTeminationStatus);
    }

    CloseHandle(hRemoteThread);
    CloseHandle(hProcess); 
    injected = false;
    return DLLEJECT_OK;
}
```

Comment: NB: you shouldn't be calling `FreeLibrary(hModule)` as per the documentation for `GetModuleHandle()`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On 32-bit systems, the value of `ThreadTeminationStatus` after `GetExitCodeThread` contains the return value of `LoadLibraryA` in the remote process.
This is the module handle of the newly loaded dll.
You can use it as the parameter to `FreeLibrary` in the remote thread.

If you want to use the code on 64-bit Windows, the thread exit code is truncated to a 32-bit `DWORD`, so it's unusable.
You have to create a callable routine in the remote process (as Necrolis suggested) or resort to finding the module base of the DLL via psapi or the [Toolhelp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686832%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) API (`CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`, `Module32First`, `Module32Next`).

Answer (score 6):

You need to pass it the `HANDLE` of the dll you injected, else you can pass it `VirtualMem` but then your remote thread routine would need to be:

```
DWORD WINAPI UnloadDll(void* pMem)
{
    FreeLibrary(GetModuleHandleA((const char*)pMem));
    return 0;
}
```

However, generally the dll you inject should unload itself (see how [`DllMain` works](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), either manually or automatically when the host is closed.

Comment: which one of the handles from those i got in InjectDll() function i need to pass as parameter in the EjectDll() CreateRemoteThread Function ?
or i just should get the handle like that: hModule = GetModuleHandle(L"c:\\myinjecteddll.dll"); ?

Comment: @DanRevah: you need to pass the `HANDLE`(or `HMODULE` if you want to be fully correct) returned from the call to `LoadLibrary` else use `GetModuleHandle`